# Why is $(\gcd(f,g)) = (f,g)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

$f$ and $g$ are polynomials of $F[X]$.
I can't see why $(f,g) = (\gcd(f,g))$ ?

(the ideal that $f$ and $g$ are the generators, and the ideal that the $\gcd$ is the generator).

$\gcd(f,g) = a\cdot f+b\cdot g$ , for specific $a$ and $b$, so how come it generates all the combinations of $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $h \in (f, g)$. Then we can write $h = af + bg$; but since both $f$ and $g$ are multiples of $\gcd(f, g)$, so is $h$. Hence $h \in (\gcd(f, g))$. This proves that
$$(f, g) \subseteq (\gcd(f, g))$$

The reverse inclusion follows from the fact that there must exist $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which $$\gcd(f, g) = \alpha f + \beta g$$

Comment: I don't understand the part of: (f,g)⊆(gcd(f,g)) . let's say x is the gcd, x= A*f+ B*g. t is some combination: t = C*f + D*g. then x|f, x|g and t|x. so x=t*q, q is polynomial. if it was t=q*x i could see it was right, because it was in (gcd(f,g)) but it isnt..